# Laravel SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to delete a faculty but I have this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`trouverm_m_ecole`.`etablissement_filieres`, CONSTRAINT `etablissement_filieres_id_filieres_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_filieres`) REFERENCES `filieres` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `filieres` where `id` = 1)

My migration

```
Schema::create('etablissement_filieres', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->bigInteger('id_etablissements')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('id_etablissements')->references('id')->on('etablissements');
    $table->bigInteger('id_filieres')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('id_filieres')->references('id')->on('filieres');
    $table->string('prise_en_charge');
    $table->string('prix');
    $table->string('prix_affecte')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

my controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Filiere::destroy($id);

    return redirect('/tableau-de-bord/admin/dashboard/sindhost/toutes-les-filieres');
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, there is a **etablissement_filieres** record referencing a record of **filieres**. Unless you have specified what to do when deleting a record refered by another record as a foreign key, it does not allow you to delete the foreign key record. Ideal way to handle this situation is to specify what to do when deleting a foreign key record. Check the [Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) of Laravel documentation to see the available options. Look at the section where it shows how to define the actions such as,

> ->onUpdate('cascade')
> ->onDelete('cascade');